# Closed form for multiplicative recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

In [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505424/iteration-n-fn-1n-1-fn-2), I found an interesting recurrence relation:

$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & n \leq 2 \\ nf(n-1) + (n-1)f(n-2) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

I [plugged it into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%281%29%3D1%2C+f%282%29+%3D+1%2C+f%28n%29+%3D+n*f%28n-1%29+%2B+%28n-1%29*f%28n-2%29), and it gives me the solution:

$$f(n) = \frac{2~\Gamma(n+3) - 5~!(n+2)}{n+1}$$

How would a human being go about solving something like this? Could I use generating functions in some clever way?

Comment: Maple says this here $a(n)={\frac {-5\,\Gamma  \left( k+3,-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{-1}}+2\, \left( k+
2 \right) !}{k+1}}
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly reverse-engineered; I don't know whether I would have come up with it without knowing the answer – but it's certainly something that someone with much experience with such things could come up with.

First, note that both values of $f$ are being multiplied by one more than their argument, so the right-hand side suggests considering $g(n)=(n+1)f(n)$. That yields

$$
\frac{g(n)}{n+1} = \begin{cases} 1 & n \leq 2 \\ g(n-1) + g(n-2) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

Multiply through by $n+1$:

$$
g(n) = \begin{cases} n+1 & n \leq 2 \\ (n+1) (g(n-1) + g(n-2)) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

Now both the factorial $n!$ and the subfactorial $!n$ satisfy the recurrence

$$f(n+2)=(n+1)(f(n+1)+f(n))\;.$$

(This is an elementary arithmetic fact for the factorial, and a combinatorial identity about derangements for the subfactorial.)

This is almost what we have; we just need to shift the argument by $2$. So replace $g(n)$ by $h(n+2)$:

$$
h(n+2)=\begin{cases} n+1 & n \leq 2 \\ (n+1) (h(n+1) + h(n)) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

This is the recurrence for $n!$ and $!n$, so we know two linearly independent solutions and can superimpose them with coefficients to be determined to satisfy the initial conditions:

$$
h(n)=an!+b!n\;,\\
h(3)=6a+2b=2\;,\\
h(4)=24a+9b=3\;.
$$

Thus $a=2$ and $b=-5$, and substituting back we get

$$
f(n)=\frac{g(n)}{n+1}=\frac{h(n+2)}{n+1}=\frac{2(n+2)!-5!n}{n+1}\;,
$$

which is Wolfram|Alpha's result (up to their tendency to express factorials in terms of the gamma function).

Comment: This is cool. I'll leave it open for a bit to see if someone finds something more solid. Your solutions assumes that $n!$ and $!n$ are the only solutions to the recurrence you wrote in §4, right? ($f(n+2) = (n + 1)(f(n +1)+f(n))$)

Comment: @Mauris: No. Your recurrence is well-defined, so there can be only one solution. We have a solution so it's *the* solution -- no assumptions made.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\Gamma(n+3)=(n+2)!$.

$$f(n) = \frac{2\Gamma(n+3) - 5!(n+2)}{n+1}=\frac{2(n+2)! - 5 \cdot !(n+2)}{n+1}$$

Once one has this form, it is not hard using induction:

\begin{align*} f(n+1)&=(n+1)f(n)+nf(n-1) \\ &=\frac{2(n+2)! - 5 \cdot !(n+2)}{n+1}(n-2)+\frac{2(n+1)! - 5 \cdot !(n+1)}{n}n \\ &= 2(n+2)! - 5 \cdot !(n+2) + 2(n+1)! - 5 \cdot !(n+1) \\ &= 2(n+2)(n+1)! - 5 \cdot !(n+2) + 2(n+1)! - 5 \cdot !(n+1)  \\ &= 2(n+3)(n+1)! - 5 \cdot !(n+2) - 5 \cdot !(n+1)  \\ &= 2(n+3)(n+1)! - 5 \cdot (!(n+2)+ !(n+1)) \\&= \frac{[2(n+3)(n+1)! - 5 \cdot (!(n+2)+ !(n+1))](n-2)}{n-2} \\&= \frac{2(n+3)(n-2)(n+1)! - 5(n-2) \cdot (!(n+2)+ !(n+1))}{n-2} \\&= \frac{2(n+3)! - 5 \cdot !(n+3)}{n+2}\end{align*}

The last step uses the recurrence relation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements).

---

To find such formula, just notice that the closed form is the sum of a lot of factorials, and you could probably find it by writing it as factorials while doing some small cases.

Comment: I think the question was how to come up with this result, not how to prove its correctness once it's known?

Comment: Yes, this isn't very useful, sorry :(